# How to see/test responsive design on multiple devices simultaneously?

Tags: responsive-design

Is there a way to work with site and instantly see how it looks on multiple devices?

For example, You have two monitors, and You open 3 browser windows of different sizes (PC, Tablet, Phone). 
PC version is the main version and You work with it on the main monitor, and just time from time look Tablet and Phone versions on the other monitor. 
You click on link on PC version and go to new page, two other do the same.

Is there any tool to do that?

Comment: As far as I know, simply re-sizing the browser on your PC is not enough. Different devices all display web pages slightly differently due to hardware and software differences. They will all render the same webpage differently from one another. The best way to see the most accurate results is to... view the page on the devices themselves. Sorry!

Comment: @dykeag Yea, probably You need a real device for final polishing. This is mainly to take a quick glance and instantly catch majority of errors.

Answer (score 2):

For testing responsive web design, I use web based tool called The Responsinator.

You enter URL and hit Go. That's all.

> http://www.responsinator.com/?url=[your URL here]

Hope it helps! :)

EDIT:

PS: SO far, it has not shown any 'wrong' results however, a client feedback should be awaited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [isresponsive.com](http://www.isresponsive.com) to test your responsive design on different devices.